# How to create a model with table names as integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Is there a way to generate modles with table field names as numbers
`rails g model Numbers 1-10:string 11-20:string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do this according to both SQL Standards and Ruby Syntax.

[PostgreSQL 4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

> **SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_).** Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less portable. The SQL standard will not define a key word that contains digits or starts or ends with an underscore, so identifiers of this form are safe against possible conflict with future extensions of the standard.

Many SQL servers will allow columns starting with numbers though such as MSSQL, and MySQL/MariaDB however referencing these columns requires the need for explicit double quotes/square brackets (MSSQL) or backticks (MySQL/MariaDB) otherwise 1-10 would be considered a expression rather than a column reference thus resulting in `-9`.

Also even if this wasn't true ruby does not allow method names to begin with a number so this would make for very awkward code usage.

> Method names may be one of the operators or must start a letter or a character with the eight bit set. It may contain letters, numbers, an _ (underscore or low line) or a character with the eight bit set. The convention is to use underscores to separate words in a multiword method name.

Comment: You can make identifiers like that, a little further down: **"There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word."** You can also make Ruby methods with "odd" names using `define_method` (e.g. `define_method(:'1-10') { 6 }; send(:'1-10')`). They're both horrible things to do to yourself though and can be an ongoing source of frustration.

Comment: @muistooshort you are correct thus "You **should not do this**..." rather than "You **cannot do this**..."